# Error creating custom onClick handler for ReactRouter Links

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, reactive-programming

I am trying to write a portals list page which is a table of portals, Each of the table row is a link to portal. Now I have to take some custom action on this click. My code looks like-

```js
var React = require('react');
var Link = require('react-router').Link;

var PortalStore = require('../../stores/portal-store');

var PortalLandingPage = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function () {
        return PortalStore.getPortalList();
    },
    updateAuthorizationCookie: function (portalIdHash) {
        PortalStore.setPortalIdHash(portalIdHash);
        PortalStore.generateAuthToken();
        this.transitionTo('portalHome', {portalIdHash: portalIdHash});
    },
    render: function () {
        var createPortalRow = function (portal) {
            return (
                <tr key={portal.portalId}>
                    <td>
                        <Link to='portalHome'
                              params={{
                                  portalIdHash: portal.portalIdHash,
                                  contentId: portal.portalId
                              }}
                              onClick={this.updateAuthorizationCookie(portal.portalIdHash)}
                        >{portal.portalName}</Link>
                        <b></b>
                        <hr align="left" width="100%"></hr>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        };
  return (
   <table className="table">
    <thead>
    <tr><th>
     Name
     <b></b>
     <hr align="left" width="100%"></hr>
    </th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {this.state.portalList.map(createPortalRow, this)}
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>);
    }
}
module.exports = PortalLandingPage;
```

Now problem is when render method of above component is being called, it also call and evaluate onClick handler for each row. Instead my requirement is that onClick handler will only be called when user clicks on the link. I also tried, removing parentheses around handler, but it gives compile time error.

```js
<Link to='portalHome'
                              params={{
                                  portalIdHash: portal.portalIdHash,
                                  contentId: portal.portalId
                              }}
                              onClick=this.updateAuthorizationCookie(portal.portalIdHash)
                        >{portal.portalName}</Link>
```

Please suggest what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function you are passing to onClick, so when the event is called it will try and call the **result** of that function (which is undefined). You need to pass the function reference itself, or since you are using arrow functions, pass an anonymous function which calls your function:

```
onClick={() => this.updateAuthorizationCookie(portal.portalIdHash)}
```